# Повторение слова - какая функция в этих примерах?

Tags: значения

> Прямо готовая реклама по технике безопасности - **что-что**, а череп у него остался совершенно цел, и зубы были просто идеальные - ровные, аккуратные, я такими похвастаться не мог.
>
> Наши пальцы сцепились сами, и я обнял её **крепко-крепко**.

(В. Березин, *Путевые знаки*)

Какая в этих примерах функция повторения? Я понимаю первый пример как *чуть-чуть*, а второй как *всё крепче*. Прав ли я?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Что-что, а" служит для выделения объекта речи http://translate.academic.ru/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE,%20%D0%90/ru/

"Крепко-крепко" = очень крепко.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не совсем правы. В первом примере имеется в ввиду что череп остался цел, а остальные части тела нет. Во втором примере повторение используется для усиления: "крепко-крепко" означает "очень крепко".